# Measuring total network traffic in Android Studio 3.0 Network Profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, profiling

I'm trying to use the new Network Profiler to gather statistics on the overall volume of network data my app is using in a period of time. I can select a section of the network traffic (though it doesn't seem to scroll while selecting, which is a separate problem) and get a list of requests and responses with sizes, but there's no total. In other parts of Android Studio (such as logging), I can select all of the output and (for example) copy it into a spreadsheet, and set that up to calculate the total of the size column, but Network Profiler doesn't seem to let me select more than one entry. Shift-down-arrow doesn't do it, and Command- or control-A doesn't do select-all, it opens another view on the request.

Is there something I'm missing? Has anyone else figured this out? It seems like total traffic is something that should be a part of network profiling.